# Value from nameValuePairs not successfully passed to database

Tags: php, android

I am using nameValuePairs in passing my datas to the database. The values inside it are from a map. I put it into a string then put the string to the nameValuePairs. My php seems to work fine. My goal here is to update my table containing counts using the where inside my SQL statement.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "nearbyme");
$namelocation = $_GET['namelocation'];
$count = $_GET['count'];

$sql = "UPDATE place SET count= '$count' WHERE namelocation='$namelocation' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($result){
echo "Updated!";
}else{
echo "failed"; 
}
?>
```

This is my Activity in passing the datas using nameValuePairs.

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private List<LocationModel> mListMarker = new ArrayList<>();
public String category;
public String mood;
public String name;
public int i;
public String desc;
public int count = 0;
//private static final String insertURL = "http://192.168.0.26/php2/UpdateCount.php";
//private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
String DataParseUrl = "http://192.168.254.105/php2/UpdateCount.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    assert mapFragment != null;
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    getAllDataLocationLatLng();
}

private void getAllDataLocationLatLng() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading Marker ..");
    dialog.show();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    category = i.getExtras().getString("category");
    mood = i.getExtras().getString("mood");
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call<ListLocationModel> call = apiService.getAllLocation("JsonDisplayMarker.php?category=" + category + "&mood=" + mood);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListLocationModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListLocationModel> call, Response<ListLocationModel> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            mListMarker = response.body().getmData();
            initMarker(mListMarker);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListLocationModel> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void initMarker(final List<LocationModel> listData) {
    for (i = 0; i < mListMarker.size(); i++) {
        //requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());
        name = mListMarker.get(i).getImageLocationName().trim();
        desc = mListMarker.get(i).getDescription();
        LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLatutide()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLongitude()));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(name).snippet(desc));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(0).getLatutide()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(0).getLongitude()));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 16));
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("namelocation", marker.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("description", marker.getSnippet());
                intent.putExtra("count", String.valueOf(count++));
                //SendDataToServer(marker);
                class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

  //HERE IS THE PASSING OF THE DATA

                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namelocation",name));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count",String.valueOf(count)));
                        try {
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);

                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                        }
                        return "Data Submit Successfully";
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
                sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, String.valueOf(count));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            });


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your `logcat` also

Answer (score 0):

in your php script change

```
$namelocation = $_GET['namelocation'];
$count = $_GET['count'];
```

to

```
$namelocation = $_REQUEST['namelocation'];
$count = $_REQUEST['count'];
```

Comment: I changed it sir but still it didn't pass anything to my database. How can I see see from my android if there is really a data in my nameValuePairs?

Comment: You can check using debugger or printing Log. Also try to send static data to ensure your request is getting called

Comment: this post has been solved sirs. thanks for helping out! it was just from the value of the data passed. i was tweaking it little bit.